# Image with src "/images/logo.png" was detected as the Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image

I am trying to do a project in Next.13 and Typescript. I have created a component named `Logo.tsx` to render an **Image**.

```
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const Logo = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <Image
      alt="logo"
      height="100"
      width="100"
      className="
        hidden
        md:block  
        cursor-pointer
      "
      src="/images/logo.png"
    />
  );
};

export default Logo;
```

But I am getting this warning.

```
Image with src "/images/logo.png" was detected as the Largest Contentful Paint (LCP). Please add the "priority" property if this image is above the fold.
```

I looked into the documentation but could not understand properly. How can remove this error?

I have tried adding the prop, `priority` like this,

```
    <Image
      priority="true"
      alt="logo"
      height="100"
      width="100"
      className="
        hidden
        md:block  
        cursor-pointer
      "
      src="/images/logo.png"
    />
```

But I am still getting the warning. And there is a new error in the Eslint,

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the official documentation of [next/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#priority).

The TypeScript error you are getting should be a hint, what you are doing wrong. `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'` That means, that the `priority` prop expects either a `boolean` or `undefined`, but you provided a `string`.

```
 <Image
      priority={true} // Change this line
      alt="logo"
      height="100"
      width="100"
      className="
        hidden
        md:block  
        cursor-pointer
      "
      src="/images/logo.png"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to typescript and nextjs both so I could not figure it out. But by tweaking it I solved it. Thank you for your answer anyway. Have a nice day.